# Cassandra request_response messages are getting dropped.

Tags: cassandra

Any one had any idea about REQUEST_RESPONSE message drops in cassandra. What could be the reasons for this behaviour?

Sample log:

DEBUG [SharedPool-Worker-2] 2018-XX-XX 13:55:30,596 MessageDeliveryTask.java:52 - Message dropped; constructionTime: 1521726918889, isCrossNodeTimestamp: false, 
timeout: 10000, message: FROM:/XX.XX.XXX.XXX TYPE:REQUEST_RESPONSE VERB:REQUEST_RESPONSE SIZE:146018

Thanks